# ADF Raster File to TIN Points?

Tags: qgis, raster, arcmap, tin

I received a folder containing different .adf files ranging in size. My task is to turn this into a TIN file which then I can bring into Microstation.  I have searched the web for days and it all leads back to using 3D Analyst in ArcMap, something I do not have access to.  My ArcMap skills aren't the greatest as I was just thrown onto this program.

Is there any other way to create a TIN from these .adf raster files?

Does Bentley Map do such a thing?

[image: files I received]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Unfortunately, this isn't even a *complete* binary dataset. I suggest you request a GeoTIFF from your data provider.

Comment: I'm not sure about microstation TINs, they are quite likely to be something completely different to an Esri TIN so even with 3d analyst you could be barking up the wrong tree. What you have here is most of a raster.. there might be enough here for QGIS (GDAL) to open it. If you know how to create a TIN in microstation you could convert the raster to points with QGIS, import the points into microstation and TIN there.

Comment: This is likely Arc/Info Binary Grid, and [SAGA GIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/) may help. (1) To read adf, `menu | Geoprocessing | File | Grid | Import | Import ESRI Arc/Info Grid`. (2) To create TIN, `menu | Geoprocessing | TIN | Conversion | Grid to TIN (Surface Specific Points)`.

Comment: Use R, you could raster::raster(adf) then anglr::as mesh3d() that, `max_triangles` arg controls density